# How to check Postgres version compatibility with spring data jpa?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, version-compatibility

I have been using Postgres version 10.6 in my spring-boot project but now we are going to upgrade the Postgres version from 10.6 to 13.6. how should I check the version compatibility of the Postgres 13.6 with my current code? I am using spring-data-jpa.

Comment: [see] (https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) . Also you should write a test when you develop your app. then you are change anything and you can run tests and check all work fine or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the version of your `spring-data-jpa` dependency in your project.

As a quick reference, latest `spring-data-jpa` v2.7.x uses the following PostgreSQL jdbc version:

```
<postgresql>42.2.19</postgresql>
```

On another hand, recent `pgjdbc` versions are all compatible with **PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher, and Java 8 (JDBC 4.2)** and higher as per this [link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html)

Therefore, it is all about checking the version of `spring-data-jpa` you are using, and upgrading to PostgreSQL 13 should prove no issues when you do.